# Display text in a particular div on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```js
function Hover(){
  if(a){
    //do something
    }
  else
    //disable delete button
    }
```

```html
<div ID="dynamicDivFirstModule"  >

  <%--  Dynamic Div--%>
        <div id="dynamicDiv"  style="display:none; border:solid;" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1" rowspan="2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" style="overflow:auto;" Height="102px" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td id="hoverHere">
                        <asp:Label ID="Hovar" runat="server" Text="?"></asp:Label>
                        <p id="hover" class="masterTooltip" onmouseover="Hover();">?</p>
                                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="removeDiv" />
                            
                    </td>
                </tr>
              
            </table>
        </div>
    
  <%--  Dynamic Div--%>
    </div>
```

How can I display text when mouse come over `id="hover"`? I want to display conditional text? on mouse over display text if a is true else display other text... the text should be displayed inside `id=DynamicDiv` only

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display the desired text inside a `#target_element`:

```
$('#hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
   if (a) {
      var text = 'a is true';
   } else {
      var text = 'a is false';
   }
   $('#DynamicDiv').find('#target_element').html(text);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
   $('#DynamicDiv').find('#target_element').empty();
});
```

Comment: Have you added the #target_element in the DOM?

Comment: yes did this :                     $('#DynamicDiv').find('#dynamicDiv').html(text);
                }).on('mouseleave', function () {
                    $('#DynamicDiv').find('#dynamicDiv').empty();
                });

Comment: not going inside this function : $('#hover').on('mouseenter', function() {

Answer (score 0):

Just write it as below:

```
function Hover(){
    if(a){
         $("#selector").text('Whatever Text you want to display here');
    }
    else
         $("#selector").text('Someother Text you want to display here');
    }
}
```

**Note** - `#selector` is the `id` of the `div` where you want to display text!

Comment: not working :/
i did this :  function Hover() {
               
                    $("#dynamicDiv").text('Whatever Text you want to display here');
              
            
            }